# How to verify a user's password using "github.com/go-ldap/ldap/v3"?

Tags: authentication, go, ldap

I currently check a username/password combination by connecting the LDAP server and doing a bind request. This seems a very expensive way of checking.

I found some information that there exists some extended password operation to let the LDAP server do the password verify process.

Assuming I have already connected the LDAP server and have a connection handle, i.e. call it ldapHandle, and I have connected the LDAP server with some legitimated user, what do I need to do on the handle to do the password verification?

```
ldapHanle := ldap.DialURL(...)
ldapHandle.StartTLS(...)
ldapHandle.ExternalBind() // SASL/EXTERNAL
```

If a user name was Bob and its password "secret" and if the users DN is uid=bob,o=example, how can I now verify his password with the handle?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Edit: 13:30:

I found out that I can do a re-bind, which is a workaround. But a clean solution LDAP-like would be nice to know